# Multithreading and lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I have a question in multithreading subject as describe

```
    private List<Email> emails = new List<Email>();

    private void AddEmail(Email email)
    {
        lock (this.emails)
        {
            this.emails.Add(email);
        }
    }

    private void ReadEmails()
    {
        foreach (Email email in this.emails)
        {
            Print(email);
        }
    }
```

Assume the ReadEmails method lasts in 10s and at that time the AddEmail is called. So does any error occur?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without telling us what language this is supposed to be -- what happens is entirely implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ReadEmails` method is not thread-safe. You have a couple of options.

**Option #1:**

You can place a `lock` around the entire `foreach` loop.

```
private void ReadEmails()
{
  lock (emails)
  {
    foreach (Email email in this.emails)
    {
      Print(email);
    }
  }
}
```

**Option #2:**

You can make a copy of the list inside a `lock`. Then you can iterate the copy lock-free.

```
private void ReadEmails()
{
  List<Email> copy;
  lock (emails)
  {
    copy = new List<Email>(this.emails);
  }
  foreach (Email email in copy)
  {
    Print(email);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, however a little advice @Bac, the best practice is to use a different object for locking, like `private readonly object _locker = new object();` and lock on that object instead...

Comment: Well, to be fair, `emails` is already declared private so using a different object in this case won't buy you a whole lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely add the Lock method in the Read method.  If you do not do this, there is a possibility that the email is added when the Read process hasn't been completed yet.  Since the foreach method requires its collection to be unchangeable during the iteration, the exception will be raised.

```
 private void ReadEmails()
    {
        lock(emails) {
             foreach (Email email in this.emails) {
                Print(email);
             }
        }
    }
```